# How can my son access my iTunes account from his windows 8 'sign on' on my computer?

Tags: windows, home-sharing

I want my son to be able to access my full iTunes library without signing in to my Microsoft account on my Windows 8 pc.  He has his own Microsoft account/sign in. I have tried Home Sharing, but this seams only to work if he has a different computer (and we only have this one). I do not want to create a separate iTunes account for him.  When he opens iTunes and looks at the songs list, he can see some, but not all of the songs in my library. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple provides an answer to this question.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1203)

In short:

- Quit **iTunes**
- Go to **\Users*username*\Music\iTunes** (where ***username*** is your
- Move the **iTunes Media** (might be **iTunes Music**) folder to a public folder, e.g. **\Users\Public\Public Music**
- Now, on each Windows account:

  - Launch **iTunes**
  - In the **Edit** menu, select **Preferences**
  - Click the **Advanced** icon**
  - Click the **Change** button
  - Navigate to **\Users\Public\Public Music** (or whatever public folder you moved your music to)
  - Click **OK**

You should be all set. If you’re not, that might be because iTunes for Windows apparently doesn’t automatically move your music to its **iTunes Media** folder. *In the account which holds the music*:

- Launch **iTunes**
- In the **File** menu, select **Library > Organize > Consolidate Library**. Your music will be *copied* into the **iTunes Media** folder. You may want to do a bit of cleanup to avoid data duplication.

Comment: if you found a question worthy a answer without need for additional questions... give the OP vote up :)

Comment: @Buscar웃 True. I tend to vote up questions which are of particular interest to me, but voting up well written question does make sense.